# JMS Listener & Sender - Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring-jms

I want to understand a java program and need to modify which was developed using jms spring framework. Typically it has JMS receiver & sender, it receives a message from request queue and will invoke a job (another java program) once the job is completed the sender will send response to response queue. Have couple of questions which are below,

1. The request message is not deleted until response posted into response queue successfully. How its been achieved what is the logic behind it.
2. I want to write a functionality of writing response into flat file when sender fails to send message (by catching JMS exception). Once the sender queue is up and running i will read flat file and will send responses. The reason i need is because its involved in job processing could be in hours if job failed then input message will be read again by receiver. I want to avoid duplicate processing. Please suggest your ideas here.

Comment: Why would sending the message fail? Shouldn't this be extremely rare?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the configuration it's hard to answer these questions, but best guess is that #1 is because the app is using a transactional session. This means all updates on that session are not completed until the transaction is committed.

Just catch the exception and write the data; as long as the transaction commits (because you caught the exception) the input message will be removed.